# Solution explanation - Prove that a topology space has a base composed of both open and closed sets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ topological space, meaning every single point is a closed set, and assume that for any closed set $F$ of $X$ and any continuous function $f:F \longrightarrow \left\{ 0,1\right\} $ there exists a continuous extension $f:X \longrightarrow \left\{ 0,1\right\}$.

Prove that the space has a base composed of sets which are both open and closed.

Here's a solution I found:

> let $x\in X $ and a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $x$. Then $F=\left\{x\right\} \bigcup X\setminus\mathcal{U} $ is a closed set. Define:
> $ f:F\longrightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\}  $
> by $ f\left(x\right)=0,...,f\left(X\setminus\mathcal{U}\right)=1$.
> So $f $ is continous, and if we'll take the continuous extenstion $ \tilde{f}:X\longrightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\}  $ then $ \tilde{f}^{-1}\left(0\right)$ is both open and closed and $x\in \tilde{f}^{-1}\left(0\right) \subseteq \mathcal{U}$. Which means that $X$ has a base of both closed and open sets.

**What I dont understand:**
How the definition of $f$ implies that $f$ is continuous, and why does $ \tilde{f}^{-1}\left(0\right) $ is both open and closed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is continuous iff the preimage of any closed set is closed. So, you just have to check that the following sets are closed:

1. $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})$.
2. $f^{-1}(\{0\})$.
3. $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.
4. $f^{-1}(\varnothing)$.

You should be able to do this by the definition of $f$ itself (over here, you need to also understand that $F$ is being given the subspace topology. But since $F$ is closed, this won't make a difference to anything). I also want to point out that $\mathcal{U}$ needs to be an open nbhd of $x$ in order for $F$ to be closed in the topological space.

Next, let $f_1$ be your continuous extension. Observe that $\{0\}$ is both open and closed in the discrete topology. Since $f_1$ is continuous, it follows that $f_1^{-1}(\{0\})$ is both open and closed.

Comment: The definition I know is continuous iff the preimage of any open set is open, those two definitions equivalent? what about a function which defined on an open domain but the image is constant?

Comment: Yep those two definitions are the same. The requirement behind the definition is that you are considering a function $f: X \to Y$ between two topological spaces. The same theorem will hold once you specify the appropriate topologies on the new (open) domain (and this is going to be the subspace topology).